# Grouped UITableView row animation quirks

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview

I've got a grouped UITableView with a couple of rows, and I'm animating a few more rows in and out on the toggle of a button. The problem is that with any of the row animation types I'm using (top & bottom) the animation looks horrible! Here's a screenshot mid-animation:

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [michaelwaterfall.com](http://files.michaelwaterfall.com/images/uitableview-animation.png))</sub>

Is there a reason why it's looking so bad? Or do all grouped table view animations look this shocking!?

I think it only looks so bad when the first or last row in a section is being animated, so I'm just wondering if there's any way to get it looking a bit better!? Otherwise I think I'll just call reloadData and have it all just appear.

Thanks for your help!

Michael

Comment: I've never had a problem with the animations, but I've only used the ungrouped style.  I'll answer once I test some things.

Comment: Looks like your image link isn't valid anymore; want to upload it to imgur and re-link it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you remove, add and/or move several rows in a `UITableView` at the same time, then you must enclose all these calls with `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. Otherwise the result is undetermined.

For example:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newRows 
                    withAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:invalidRows:
                    withAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Ah great, I'll try that out soon as I can! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what looks bad. It is hard to tell from a static picture.

Unfortunately you have no control over the insertion/deletion animation in a tableviews. It is all handled by the high level UITableView API.

The only other option is to perform the animations separately and consecutively and see if that looks any better.  I've done this to eliminate some artifacts.

Also try different animations like the fade in/out. Not as flashy, but looks better in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

I've used animations in a grouped table view without any problem, and it always looked great. How about sharing some of the code? Maybe you're doing something wrong in the cell building... or although unlikely in the insertion of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, posting some code would help.

Are you already performing your multiple inserts/deletes inside of a [beginUpdates/endUpdates](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15) block?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, please see [#6931544](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931544/obj-c-class-conform-to-protocol-as-parameter). I've found these arbitrary lines mid transition can be removed with the following: -

```
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```