# Declare an ObjC parameter that's a Class conforming to a protocol

Tags: objective-c, class, syntax, protocols

In Objective-C, it is possible to pass a class as a parameter to a method:

```
- (void) methodThatTakesClass:(Class)theClass;
```

And it is possible to pass an instance that is conforming to a protocol as a parameter:

```
- (void) myConformInstance:(id <MyProtocol>)theObject;
```

Is it possible to use the combined functionality? A method which takes a class which is conforming to a certain protocol.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. The following is a valid program which will log the NSObject class.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
void f(Class <NSObject> c) {
    NSLog(@"%@",c);
}
int main() {
    f([NSObject class]);
}
```

This would cause a compiler error if you tried to pass a class which doesn't conform to NSObject, such as the `Object` class. You can also use it for methods.

```
- (void)printClass:(Class <NSObject>)c;
```

Comment: From [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html): "Protocols can’t be used to type class objects. Only instances can be statically typed to a protocol, just as only instances can be statically typed to a class. (However, at runtime, both classes and instances respond to a conformsToProtocol: message.)"

Comment: @albertamg Good find. However, at least some compilers let it through. The rule could be because you can't change the object representing the class to conform to a protocol.

Answer (score -2):

also valid:

```
@interface Something: Object {
}
 - (void) foo:(int(*)(void))bar;
@end

@implementation Something
- (void) foo:(int(*)(void))bar {
   return (*bar)();
}
@end

int someFunc( void ) {
    return 9;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    Something *object = [[Something alloc] init];

    printf( "%i\n", [object foo:&someFunc] );

    [object release];

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer to a completely different question.