# Create an instance from a Class that conforms to a Protocol

Tags: objective-c, class, protocols

I'm trying to accomplish something like the following:

```
- (id<SomeProtocol>)instanceFromClass:(Class<SomeProtocol>)cls
{
    return [[cls alloc] initUsingSomeConstructorDefinedInProtocolWithValue:_value];
}
```

However, I'm getting a `No Known class method for selector 'alloc'` error. How may I specify in my signature that I want to receive a class that conforms to a protocol? Or, if that part is correct, how may I create an instance from that argument using a constructor defined in the specified protocol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why the compiler complains but you can fix by casting your parameter back to `Class`

```
- (id<SomeProtocol>)instanceFromClass:(Class<SomeProtocol>)cls
{
    return [[(Class)cls alloc] initUsingSomeConstructorDefinedInProtocolWithValue:_value];
}
```

while still getting you the type checking you want for the parameter as hinted at in this SO answer: [Declare an ObjC parameter that's a Class conforming to a protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931544/obj-c-class-conform-to-protocol-as-parameter?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Your use of the protocol is 'fine'. The issue is that the `cls` parameter is tagged as a class which conforms to a protocol that defines instance methods (the init method). This doesn't tell the compiler that the `+alloc` method is available because that is a class method on `NSObject`.

You can add the `+alloc` method to the protocol. Or you can do some casting to tell the compiler to trust you.

Comment: or make SomeProtocol extend NSObject protocol

Comment: Having the protocol extend NSObject actually didn't work for me.  I just followed @jackslash 's suggestion and cast it to `(Class)` when calling `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

`+ alloc` is a method defined by the top level class `NSObject`. When you have a class like `Class <SomeProtocol>`, the compiler only knows that this is some class and it implements `SomeProtocol` but it cannot know if that is a subclass of `NSObject` or not, since in Obj-C you can define own top-level classes that don't inherit from `NSObject` (not that this is generally a good idea but it is possible).

There is a special "hack" in the compiler that in case the type is just `Class`, the compiler will always assume that it is a subclass of `NSObject` and would only fail at runtime in case it isn't. But this hack only works for the exact type `Class` and not for `Class <SomeProtocol>` which is a distinct type.

So what you can do is to either cast to Class, so the hack works again:

```
[[(Class)cls alloc] ...]
```

or you can also do that

```
[[cls.class alloc] ...]
```

in case that `cls` will be a subclass of `NSObject` at runtime because then it will have a `+ class` method.

Note that if I call `instanceFromClass:` with a class, that does implement `SomeProtocol` but is no subclass of `NSObject` and also does not implement a `+ alloc` method, both methods above will fail at runtime and the app will crash.