# Specifying a subclass of the Class class

Tags: objective-c, class, subclass

Say I had a function that does something with a class:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(Class)class
{
    [class doSomething];
}
```

but of course the method `+ (void)doSomething` isn't defined for all classes. Let's say it's defined only for subclasses of the `SomeClass` class. How can I "restrict" the type of class of the `class` parameter that's given to the function? I want to be able to do something like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(/* type of [SomeClass class] */)class
{
    [class doSomething];
}
```

so that I don't have to resort to something like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(Class)class
{
    if (![class isSubClassOfClass:[SomeClass class]])
    {
        // error
    }
    [class doSomething];
}
```

Is this possible to do in Objective-C, and is it ever even a good idea to do something like this?

Comment: you would typically use a protocol for this. so instead of passing a class, pass an object that conforms to a protocol `id <myportocol>`. would that work for you?

Comment: @BradAllred I guess using a protocol could work, though from what I understand, I'd lose out on being able to define "default" method implementations. But it wouldn't be a bad compromise, and from what I understand currently, it seems any solution to this problem would involve some sort of compromise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-C: Class conform to protocol as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931544/obj-c-class-conform-to-protocol-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

`Class` is really a c struct that contains metadata about a class type. Structs do not have inheritance.

You can restrict a method by passing in the instance of the object type instead of the `Class` struct type.

```
- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(SomeClass *)sender
{
    Class class = [sender class];
    [class doSomething];
}
```

If your method really must accept a `Class` object as the parameter, then `isKindOfClass:` or `isSubclassOfClass` is the way to go.

Comment: This could work, but I'd need to have an instance of `SomeClass` or of a particular subclass beforehand. If I didn't have such an instance readily available, I'd have to have a line of `[[SomeClass alloc] init]` before every `doSomethingWithClass` call, and the initialized sender object would mostly likely be totally unused. But I guess there just isn't an easy way provided by the language to solve this problem without having to resort to solutions like this? Or probably attempting to restrict class types like this is an indication of bad code design?

Comment: It's an indication of bad design. I'm scratching my head for a use case for why you would ask this. The only thing I can think of is a type in your design needs a class method called before instantiating any of its objects, but even then, the `+load` method already exists for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Protocol, to create a reuse interface for your classes. If you classes conform this protocol, so it will implement method doSomething.

```
@protocol ClassProtocol

+ (void)doSomething;

@end

@interface ClassEngine : NSObject
@end

@implementation ClassEngine

- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(Class)class {

    if([class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ClassProtocol)])

        [(Class<ClassProtocol>)class doSomething];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a runtime check. I believe the OP is looking for a compile-time restriction.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mistake when use instance method, what I mean is Class method, I rechecked it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to specify such a type in Objective-C. But it's possible in Swift -- `SomeClass.Type`