# Middle animation in grouped table view looks horrible

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-animation

I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195540/grouped-uitableview-row-animation-quirks), but there is no answer (sorry, answer just doesn't work).

So I have grouped table and I want to animate content update instead of doing `[tableView reloadData]`.
I do that by using this piece of code:

```
// Data source already updated here, but reloadData wasn't called
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I uploaded 2 examples of the animation:

- Plain: http://cl.ly/3u1M3l1w3V3J (slow motion)
- Grouped: http://cl.ly/1O3Z2M280n0z (slow motion)

As you can see difference is huge.
I don't change my code at all, just change tableView style in the storyboard.

Does it men that there is no other way then subclassing UITableView and UITableViewCell and implement my very own animation using CoreAnimation?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your own animation with CoreAnimation shouldn't be necessary when it comes to animating the rows of the table.

UITableView supports much more advanced animations than simply reloading a section and I suggest that you take a look at them.

Since you are shuffling the rows in your videos you should take a look at `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` (on UITableView). You put the calls to it within `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

By knowing the order before and after the re-shuffle you can move all the rows into their new places and have them slide into their correct place.

It will take some thinking to figure out where each row should go but it will be much easier than rolling your completely custom solution.

Comment: Adding other type of animations isn't a problem. Fade animation works perfect, but we want "middle" animation with looks a bit like an airport display.